# Subtract a string in R

Tags: r

I have a string like this:

```
phrase <- "this_is.//the_first?the_second"
```

and as result I want to subtract this string based on ? and take as result this

```
>phrase_new[1]
 "this_is.//the_first?"
>phrase_new[2]
  "the_second"
```

I try this but it not working. Please is there any idea for this?

```
phrase_new <- sub("[:?:]", "", phrase)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to split it by a character, better use [`strsplit`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html):

```
> strsplit(phrase, "?", fixed = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "this_is.//the_first" "the_second"
```

Comment: Looks like OP wants to keep the `?`, so maybe `strsplit(phrase, "(?<=\\?)", perl = TRUE)` could do that.

Answer (score 2):

IF we need `sub`, we can capture the characters until the `?` as a group (`(...)`) and in the replacement, we provide the backreference (`\\1`) for that group.

```
sub("(.*\\?).*", "\\1", phrase)
#[1] "this_is.//the_first?"
```

For the second substring, we match one or more character (`.*`) until the `?` and replace it with `""`.

```
sub(".*\\?", "", phrase)
#[1] "the_second"
```

Answer (score 1):

As @m0nhawk suggested, strsplit is great to break a string. But, for you requirement to extract elements, you have to use double square brackets

```
phrase <- "this_is.//the_first?the_second"
phrase_new <- strsplit(phrase,split = '?',fixed = T)[[1]]
phrase_new[1]
phrase_new[2]
```